Filepath length on Azure Data Factory
I'm on a pipeline on ADF, I've got a copy activity that works with a linked service and a SHIR on a client's VM. He has a stupidly long folder structure and when the path exceeds 250 characters I can't read the files inside the subfolders. Data Factory and its explorer are not even showing the files. I tried to rename it to something non-exceeding like 'a.xlsx' and there I can actually read/write the files into the data lake. NOTE: I can't alter my client's folder structure. Any solutions?
P.S.: I tried to enable a long path on group policies and didn't work
I tried enabling long paths on group policies expecting to fix the SHIR limitation or idk where the problem is


I tried enable long path on group policies and didn't work

As per this Documentation,

You need to check whether you met two requirements in which

one is the registry value (This value should be set to 1). You should reboot your system after setting this to make sure that all the processes started after setting the value.
the second one is you need to ensure the Application manifest has longPathAware property.


You can check the same documentation to know how to set those properties.
You can also use \\?\ prefix to specify extended file path in the Windows API. You can specify it like \\?\Drive or UNC/server/filepath as per your requirement.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell#application-manifest-updates-to-declare-long-path-capability
